# How can I launch an activity using ListView instead of ordinary buttons? Android / Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, android-listview, android-activity

I looked up tutorials on how to launch activities from list view instead of regular buttons and I think I'm right on this but for some reason my emulator isn't launching the second activity it just shows that I've pressed the button but nothing happens.

Here's a copy of my MainActivityThree.java...

```
package testing.android.application.three;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivityThree extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_three);
    String[] names = new String[]{"Test 5","Test 10","Test 15","Test 20","Test 25","Test 30"};
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,names));

}

private static final int Test 5 = 0;
private static final int Test 10 = 1;

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    Class <?> MainActivityNext = null;
    switch(position) {
        case Test 5 :
            MainActivityNext = MainActivityNext.class;
            break;
       //keep the same logic for other cases
    }
    Intent Test 5Intent = new Intent(MainActivityThree.this, MainActivityNext);
    startActivity(Test 5Intent);

}

}
```

Here's a copy of my MainActivityNext.java...

```
package testing.android.application.three;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivityNext extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_next);

}

}
```

Here's a copy of my AndroidManifest.xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="testing.android.application.three"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/AppName"
    android:theme="@style/ThreeTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="testing.android.application.three.MainActivityThree"
        android:label="@string/AppName" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="testing.android.application.three.MainActivityNext"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main_activity_next" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="testing.android.application.three.MainActivityTGS"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main_activity_tgs" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Here's a copy of my activity_main_activity_next.xml...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivityNext" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's a copy of my actiity_main_activity_Three.xml...

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingLeft="8dp"
 android:paddingRight="8dp"
 tools:context=".MainActivityThree" >

</LinearLayout>
```

And a copy of my LogCat...

```
06-01 04:10:39.389: E/AndroidRuntime(2686):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3435)
06-01 04:10:39.389: E/AndroidRuntime(2686):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7246)
06-01 04:10:39.389: E/AndroidRuntime(2686):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2168)
06-01 04:10:39.389: E/AndroidRuntime(2686):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1903)
06-01 04:10:39.389: E/AndroidRuntime(2686):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
06-01 04:10:39.389: E/AndroidRuntime(2686):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
06-01 04:10:39.389: E/AndroidRuntime(2686):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
06-01 04:10:39.389: E/AndroidRuntime(2686):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
06-01 04:10:39.389: E/AndroidRuntime(2686):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
06-01 04:10:39.389: E/AndroidRuntime(2686):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
06-01 04:10:39.389: E/AndroidRuntime(2686):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1953)
06-01 04:10:39.389: E/AndroidRuntime(2686):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1405)
06-01 04:10:39.389: E/AndroidRuntime(2686):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2410)
06-01 04:10:39.389: E/AndroidRuntime(2686):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1901)
06-01 04:10:39.389: E/AndroidRuntime(2686):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7426)
06-01 04:10:39.389: E/AndroidRuntime(2686):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
06-01 04:10:39.389: E/AndroidRuntime(2686):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
06-01 04:10:39.389: E/AndroidRuntime(2686):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)
06-01 04:10:39.389: E/AndroidRuntime(2686):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4271)
06-01 04:10:39.389: E/AndroidRuntime(2686):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
06-01 04:10:39.389: E/AndroidRuntime(2686):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
06-01 04:10:39.389: E/AndroidRuntime(2686):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
06-01 04:10:39.389: E/AndroidRuntime(2686):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
06-01 04:10:39.389: E/AndroidRuntime(2686):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
06-01 04:10:39.389: E/AndroidRuntime(2686):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-01 04:10:39.389: E/AndroidRuntime(2686):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-01 04:10:39.389: E/AndroidRuntime(2686):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-01 04:10:39.389: E/AndroidRuntime(2686):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-01 04:10:39.389: E/AndroidRuntime(2686):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-01 04:10:39.389: E/AndroidRuntime(2686):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-01 04:13:31.379: D/dalvikvm(2794): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 50K, 7% free 2538K/2708K, paused 42ms, total 87ms
06-01 04:13:31.389: I/dalvikvm-heap(2794): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.666MB for 1127536-byte allocation
06-01 04:13:31.479: D/dalvikvm(2794): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 5% free 3639K/3812K, paused 81ms, total 81ms
06-01 04:13:31.549: D/dalvikvm(2794): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 3646K/3812K, paused 5ms+12ms, total 71ms
06-01 04:13:32.459: D/gralloc_goldfish(2794): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-01 04:13:55.189: E/InputEventReceiver(2794): Exception dispatching input event.
06-01 04:13:55.189: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:76)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3491)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at testing.android.application.three.MainActivityThree.onListItemClick(MainActivityThree.java:34)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3435)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7246)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2168)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1903)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1953)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1405)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2410)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1901)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7426)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4271)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-01 04:13:55.261: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2794):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-01 04:13:55.261: D/AndroidRuntime(2794): Shutting down VM
06-01 04:13:55.261: W/dalvikvm(2794): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:76)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3491)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at testing.android.application.three.MainActivityThree.onListItemClick(MainActivityThree.java:34)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3435)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7246)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2168)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1903)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1953)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1405)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2410)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1901)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7426)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4271)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-01 04:13:55.309: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-01 04:13:58.309: I/Process(2794): Sending signal. PID: 2794 SIG: 9
06-01 04:14:05.680: E/Trace(2835): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-01 04:14:06.710: D/dalvikvm(2835): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 54K, 7% free 2539K/2712K, paused 296ms, total 350ms
06-01 04:14:06.771: I/dalvikvm-heap(2835): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.666MB for 1127536-byte allocation
06-01 04:14:06.980: D/dalvikvm(2835): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 5% free 3639K/3816K, paused 202ms, total 202ms
06-01 04:14:07.080: D/dalvikvm(2835): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 3664K/3816K, paused 13ms+18ms, total 100ms
06-01 04:14:07.400: D/gralloc_goldfish(2835): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-01 04:14:09.749: D/AndroidRuntime(2835): Shutting down VM
06-01 04:14:09.749: W/dalvikvm(2835): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
06-01 04:14:09.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2835): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-01 04:14:09.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2835): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-01 04:14:09.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2835):     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:76)
06-01 04:14:09.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2835):     at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3491)
06-01 04:14:09.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2835):     at testing.android.application.three.MainActivityThree.onListItemClick(MainActivityThree.java:34)
06-01 04:14:09.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2835):     at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
06-01 04:14:09.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2835):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
06-01 04:14:09.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2835):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
06-01 04:14:09.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2835):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
06-01 04:14:09.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2835):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
06-01 04:14:09.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2835):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-01 04:14:09.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2835):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-01 04:14:09.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2835):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-01 04:14:09.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2835):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-01 04:14:09.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2835):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-01 04:14:09.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2835):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-01 04:14:09.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2835):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-01 04:14:09.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2835):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-01 04:14:09.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2835):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-01 04:14:12.179: I/Process(2835): Sending signal. PID: 2835 SIG: 9
06-01 04:15:20.289: D/dalvikvm(2901): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 57K, 7% free 2538K/2716K, paused 315ms, total 352ms
06-01 04:15:20.339: I/dalvikvm-heap(2901): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.666MB for 1127536-byte allocation
06-01 04:15:20.549: D/dalvikvm(2901): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 5% free 3639K/3820K, paused 203ms, total 203ms
06-01 04:15:20.659: D/dalvikvm(2901): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 3645K/3820K, paused 5ms+6ms, total 116ms
06-01 04:15:21.019: D/gralloc_goldfish(2901): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-01 04:15:24.180: D/AndroidRuntime(2901): Shutting down VM
06-01 04:15:24.180: W/dalvikvm(2901): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
06-01 04:15:24.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2901): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-01 04:15:24.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2901): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-01 04:15:24.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:76)
06-01 04:15:24.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3491)
06-01 04:15:24.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at testing.android.application.three.MainActivityThree.onListItemClick(MainActivityThree.java:34)
06-01 04:15:24.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
06-01 04:15:24.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
06-01 04:15:24.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
06-01 04:15:24.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
06-01 04:15:24.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
06-01 04:15:24.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-01 04:15:24.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-01 04:15:24.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-01 04:15:24.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-01 04:15:24.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-01 04:15:24.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-01 04:15:24.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-01 04:15:24.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-01 04:15:24.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2901):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-01 04:15:27.310: I/Process(2901): Sending signal. PID: 2901 SIG: 9
06-01 04:17:10.740: D/dalvikvm(2981): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 61K, 7% free 2538K/2720K, paused 320ms, total 340ms
06-01 04:17:10.810: I/dalvikvm-heap(2981): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.666MB for 1127536-byte allocation
06-01 04:17:11.030: D/dalvikvm(2981): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 5% free 3639K/3824K, paused 220ms, total 220ms
06-01 04:17:11.150: D/dalvikvm(2981): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 3639K/3824K, paused 12ms+34ms, total 129ms
06-01 04:17:11.500: D/gralloc_goldfish(2981): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-01 04:17:22.369: D/AndroidRuntime(2981): Shutting down VM
06-01 04:17:22.402: W/dalvikvm(2981): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
06-01 04:17:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(2981): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-01 04:17:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(2981): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-01 04:17:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(2981):     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:76)
06-01 04:17:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(2981):     at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3491)
06-01 04:17:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(2981):     at testing.android.application.three.MainActivityThree.onListItemClick(MainActivityThree.java:34)
06-01 04:17:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(2981):     at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
06-01 04:17:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(2981):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
06-01 04:17:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(2981):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
06-01 04:17:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(2981):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
06-01 04:17:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(2981):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
06-01 04:17:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(2981):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-01 04:17:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(2981):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-01 04:17:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(2981):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-01 04:17:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(2981):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-01 04:17:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(2981):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-01 04:17:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(2981):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-01 04:17:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(2981):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-01 04:17:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(2981):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-01 04:17:22.429: E/AndroidRuntime(2981):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-01 04:17:24.779: I/Process(2981): Sending signal. PID: 2981 SIG: 9
```

Comment: You can clearly see the `ClassNotFoundException` from the logs.

Comment: you can try @Atif Farrukh answer it will be right.

Comment: @silverback what can I do to fix this?

Comment: @Harshid I tried the first one and it got rid of that warning but now it has a marker with ClassNotFoundException. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually,

You might want to consider something a lot simpler

```
Class<?> clasz =  MainActivityNext.class;
Intent MainActivityNextIntent = new Intent(this, clasz);
startActivity(MainActivityNextIntent);
```

But I mean, if you are always aware of what class you are starting, why not the good ol':

```
Intent MainActivityNextIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(MainActivityNextIntent);
```

Also, if the activity that will be started depends on the Item being clicked, define them via `final int` and then access them through a switch. For example, at the begining of you class, define a few activities that could be started:

```
//Notice how I use All capitals and underscores? 
//It's a common convention for constants.
private static final int TEST_5 = 0;  //Starts MainActivityThree.class
private static final int TEST_10 = 1;  //Starts MainActivityTGS.class
private static final int TEST_15 = 2; //What do these other ones start? your call
private static final int TEST_20 = 3;
private static final int TEST_25 = 4;
private static final int TEST_30 = 5;
```

And then, based on the item that is selected, run a switch statement:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Class <?> nextClass;
    switch(position) {
        case TEST_5 :
            nextClass = MainActivityThree.class;
            break;
        case TEST_10: 
            nextClass = MainActivityTGS.class;
            break;
        default:
           //because I don't know what other classes you plan on starting
           //I call return to avoid a null pointer exception
           //You have to make sure you set a class for the other list items
           //I just don't know which oens are they. 
           return;
       //keep the same logic for other cases
    }
    //This will only be called if the list item clicked was either TEST_5, Or TEST_10
    Intent nextClassIntent = new Intent(CurrentClass.this, nextClass);
    startActivity(nextClassIntent);
    }
```

Comment: does all this go in my MainActivityThree.java?

Comment: Yes, but not all of it, pick one of the implementations, the one that suits you best.

Comment: So I got it to work choosing the second option you gave me which I found to be a lot better (Thank You) but when I touch "Test 10", "Test 15", "Test 20", "Test 25", and "Test 30" (which are the other activities in the ListView) it closes and tells me "Unfortunately, Three has closed.". Any ideas why? Do I need to connect them to activities like "Test 5" for them to work?

Comment: Is each List Item ("Test 10", etc) supposed to start a different activity? Or are they all supposed to star the same "MainActivityNext.java"? If they star different ones, then you should look into the third option of the ones I listed.

Comment: so I should use the private static and override one

Comment: Can you update your question to show the class names you want to start? And also include what list item should start which activity, then I'll  update the answer.

Comment: ok I updated my AndroidManifest.xml and MainActivityThree.java. my third activity is MainActivityTGS which goes with Test 10.

Comment: Success. Thank you for the advice this was great.

Answer (score 1):

It is class not found exception. You are mistakenly giving "+" inside the class name string.Try using this

```
    Class MainActivityNext = Class.forName("testing.android.application.three." + 
    "MainActivityNext.java");
```

instead of this

```
Class MainActivityNext = Class.forName("testing.android.application.three. + MainActivityNext.java");
```

Comment: or just...  `Class MainActivityNext = Class.forName("testing.android.application.three.MainActivityNext.java");`

Answer (score 0):

In you `try-catch` simply write

```
Intent MainActivityNextIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivityNext.class);
        startActivity(MainActivityNextIntent);
```

instead of

```
Class MainActivityNext = Class.forName("testing.android.application.three. + MainActivityNext.java");
        Intent MainActivityNextIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivityNext);
        startActivity(MainActivityNextIntent);
```

and if you wan to do that way do it like this

```
Class MainActivityNext = Class.forName("testing.android.application.three." + "MainActivityNext.java");
        Intent MainActivityNextIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivityNext);
        startActivity(MainActivityNextIntent);
```

Comment: I tried the first one and it got rid of that warning but now it has a marker with ClassNotFoundException.